# Clipping and masking a div using CSS without image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to clip a triangle inside a div `.box-inner-2` and mask the outside of that to look like:

[image]

but what I am getting now is this. How can I do this?

```css
  .wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  .box-inner-1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .box-inner-2{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 0 20%, 20% 20%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box-inner-1"></div>
 <div class="box-inner-2"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a brief of what I changed in your code:

1. Moved the *triangle* `clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 0 20%, 20% 20%)` to the `box-inner-1` (adjusted `top` and `left` for illustration)
2. Added an *inset* `clip-path` to the `box-inner-2` and a *psuedo* after element to *clip* the triangle.

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  clip-path: inset(0% 94% 0% 0%);
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-inner-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 0 20%, 20% 20%);
}

.box-inner-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  clip-path: inset(0% 0% 93% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-inner-1"></div>
  <div class="box-inner-2"></div>
</div>
```